# Spring boot 2.0.0.M7 and Oauth2 not triggering initial redirect

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring boot 2.0.0.M7, and I can't get the OAuth2 to work. I had it working for facebook and github under M4 though. (It changed in M5, and I didn't try and upgrade it then).

I can't seem to trigger the initial redirect from my app to the oauth provider. Using provider 1 (facebook), previously the /login/facebook filter would redirect for external OAuth2.
Now... I don't know the URL (possibly missing in the docs?) that I need to hit to trigger the token / redirect logic.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2 mentions /login/oauth2/code/* - but this seems to be for the provider response, and doesn't trigger the redirect.

My current configuration is below (and hooks that worked in M4 have been left in as comments)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
// ...
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
                @Override
                public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.sendRedirect("/login");
                }
            })
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/static/**", "/login", "/login/**", "/logout", "/at/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
//      .addFilterBefore(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
//      .addFilterBefore(oauthFilter("facebook"), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
//      .addFilterBefore(githubFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .rememberMe()
            .alwaysRemember(true)
        ;

        http.httpBasic().disable();
        http.formLogin().disable();
    }
// private Filter facebookFilter() {
//  @Bean @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.client") public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails facebook() {
// ...
}
```

The login page has links to /login/facebook and /login/github.

my application.yml is:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration:
  # developer.facebook.com
  facebook:
    client-id: redacted
    client-secret: redacted
  #https://github.com/settings/applications/redacted
  github:
    client-id: redacted
    client-secret: redacted
```

and since it might help, a selection of dependencies from build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.2.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.0.0.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.0.0.RELEASE'
```

I've spent ages going in circles with this. Any help welcome :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So

```
compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.2.1.RELEASE'
```

and

```
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.0.0.RELEASE'
```

are totally incompatible.
Almost no documentation around the new way of doing things. Missing information and out of date guides.

Since I'm here:

```
        //the spring security 5 way
        //OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter based config...
        http.addFilterAfter(new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter(clientRegistrationRepository), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(oAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter(), OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class);
```

along with application.yml configuration:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration:
```

Solved. Will be nice when examples and docs catch up with spring 5